How to set a ringtone for SIM2 in Android programmatically
I'm developing an Android application and I need to set a specific ringtone for the second SIM (SIM2) on devices that support dual SIM functionality.
I've tried using the RingtoneManager to set the default ringtone, but it seems to only affect the primary SIM. Here’s a snippet of my code:
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
    context,
    RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, //how to specify ringtone 2 in here?
    Uri.parse("ringtone_path")
);

However, this does not change the ringtone for SIM2.
Is there a specific API or method to set the ringtone for SIM2? If so, could you provide an example or guide me on how to achieve this?
Thanks in advance!

ask for it in the phone help Open your phone's Settings app.
Scroll to the bottom and tap About phone Send feedback about this device. If you don't see "About phone," first tap System.
Type your feedback.
Tap Send.
